# Having trouble getting IntelliJ code style to match checkstyle configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I'm using checkstyle for a Java project I'm working on, and I've got a `checkstyle.xml` that I'm happy with. However, I've found one place where it disagrees with my IntelliJ code style rules. Here's an example.

IntelliJ thinks it should be formatted like:

```
thisIsALongFunctionWithMultipleParameters(parameter1,
        andHereIsASecondFunctionWithMultipleParameters(parameter1,
                parameter2));
```

However, my checkstyle fails, and seems to think it should look like this:

```
thisIsALongFunctionWithMultipleParameters(parameter1,
        andHereIsASecondFunctionWithMultipleParameters(parameter1,
        parameter2));
```

Honestly, I don't really care which is used, but I do want them to agree. Here's the relevant section of my `checkstyle.xml`:

```
<module name="Indentation">
    <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8" />     
    <property name="throwsIndent" value="8" />
    <property name="forceStrictCondition" value="true" />
</module>
```

It seems like Checkstyle is viewing this as a simple line wrapping, and so we should have a consistent 8 space indent. IntelliJ sees it as two nested functions that each need to have an extra indent. Any idea which settings I need to change in IntelliJ to make them consistent? Or how to change my `checkstyle.xml` to accommodate?

Comment: That's one of reasons I was never able to apply `forceStrictCondition` successfully. I have it in all my projects disabled until Checkstyle will support IDEA formatting style fully